# How do I make a foreign key reference to a specific cell when the primary key is known in sql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've been searching and tackling this for hours and I'm sure there's a super easy way to do this.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Students 
(
    idnr            NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name            TEXT        NOT NULL,
    login           TEXT        NOT NULL,
    program         TEXT        NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Branches
(
    name            TEXT,
    program         TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(name, program) 
);
```

And in a third table, I want to make sure that the "program" is the same for the student and the branch.

```
CREATE TABLE StudentBranches 
(
    student         NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Students(idnr),
    branch          TEXT        NOT NULL,
    program         TEXT        NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches(name, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (student, program) REFERENCES Students(idnr, program) 
);
```

The problem I run in to is that this tries to get the whole column from program in Students. I only want the value for said student not the whole column.

To clarify:

Students:

```
idnr | name | login | program
-----+------+-------+-----------
1234 | bob  | 1111  | prog1
2222 | tom  | 2222  | prog2
```

Branches:

```
branch  | program
--------+---------
branch1 | prog1
branch2 | prog2
branch3 | prog1
```

Here Tom should only be able to enter the `StudentBranches` table with B1 and B3, since he belongs to Prog1 that is a program for B1. And Bob can only enter to B2.

Comment: Please make that clearer. I don't understand the difference between "the value for the student" and "the whole column". Maybe sample data would help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for showing the SQL for the table schema. You then write “this tries to get the whole column from program in Students”, can you update this description to show what exact SELECT query you try and what is the exact result? What result did you expect?

Comment: I added sample data to try and clearify.

Comment: Thanks! :) What im trying to get is an constraints that says "Inserts in studentbranches must have the same program for the student as for the branch entered"

Comment: I did not understand what's a record in `Branches` nor in `StudentBranches` and, in every day words, the relations between the 3 tables. From seeing the 2 "FK" to `Students` (`REFERENCES Students(idnr)` and `REFERENCES Students(idnr, program)` which I suppose is what you called "get the whole column"), I can tell you need to redesign the whole thing. Can you describe the objects in simple terms?

Comment: Yea maybe i need to do that, not sure how to fix it though. The two "FK" in studentbranches are just my guess how to solve it but it does not work. In simpler terms we have Students, who can enter specific Branches just as in a normal univ. The StudentBranches table is a "relation" between Branches and students for the student who has chosen a specific branch. But to chose the branch they need to be in a program that has that branch as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do but the foreign keys you've tried to create definitely look fishy.
Everything should be easier to understand if you limit each table to represent 1 thing only, that is respectively:

- A student (without the attached program since that would be 2 things for the same table).
- A program/branch (whatever you call it)
- The link from a student to a branch.

This results in:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    idnr            NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name            TEXT        NOT NULL,
    login           TEXT        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Branches(
    name            TEXT,
    program         TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(name, program)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentBranches (
    student         NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES Students(idnr),
    branch          TEXT        NOT NULL,
    program         TEXT        NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches(name, program)
);
```

- To fetch the program a student as registered to, you have to JOIN with `StudentBranches`.
- I have removed the `PRIMARY KEY` from `StudentBranches` because your previous comment about "get the whole column" sounded like a student should be able to register to more than 1 program. If a student can register to exactly 1 program, then you need to add it back.

Comment: Yes this is exactly how we were ment to do this thing! The program of the student should not be stored in the students table but somewhere else, that makes this whole thing alot more do-able. Thanks alot and well played figuring out what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be validated directly through a constraint, since it affects multiple tables. You're probably looking for [a trigger on insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) instead.